# PostGIS - Finding hanging line at both ends (not connected to point)

Tags: postgis

I need to find lines`(line1)` that are not connected to points at both end not connected by any lines e.g `line1`., `line2` in this case.

I tried below query but Its taking too much time even with limit 10. it keeps running.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1) t1.objectid,
                   t1.properties
FROM line1 t1,
     line1 t2,
     point1 t3,
     line2 t4
WHERE NOT ST_Intersects (t1.geom, t2.geom)
  AND t1.objectid <> t2.objectid
  AND NOT ST_Intersects(t1.geom, t3.geom)
  AND NOT ST_Intersects(t1.geom, t4.geom)
ORDER BY t1.objectid
```

Answer (score 1):

The query is taking a long time because you are almost returning a complete cross product between the 4 tables. We can expect most lines not to intersect with each others (think of a road network, streets from a city do not intersect with streets from another city).
A way to solve this is to use the opposite logic: search for lines that do intersect, and then "revert" this selection to keep the ones that don't intersect.

It would be a query similar to the following. Note that you shouldn't need the `distinct` clause anymore.

```
SELECT  t1.objectid,
         t1.properties
FROM line1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
 SELECT 1 FROM
     line1 t2,
     point1 t3,
     line2 t4
  WHERE (ST_Intersects (t1.geom, t2.geom)
      AND t1.objectid <> t2.objectid)
    OR  ST_Intersects(t1.geom, t3.geom)
    OR  ST_Intersects(t1.geom, t4.geom))
ORDER BY t1.objectid;
```

PS: This query with the `OR` will ignore lines that do intersect with any of the other layers. If you want to ignores the lines that do intersect with ALL layers, just replace the `OR` by `AND`.

PS2: of course you would need spatial index on each of the geometry columns

Comment: It still keep on running even after creating indexes?